# 2 Recurrence equations - Finding index

Tags: python, recursion, relationship, recurrence

I have some trouble figuring out a relationship between the 2 recurrence relations given below.

```
f(0) = 1  
f(1) = 1  
f(2) = 2  
f(2n) = f(n) + f(n + 1) + n          (for n > 1)  
f(2n + 1) = f(n - 1) + f(n) + 1      (for n >= 1)
```

So the series is like:(Index: 0,1,2,3...n)
1,1,2,3,7,4,13,6,15,11,22,12,25,18,28,20,34...

The goal is find the index of the occurrence of any given number which is in the series.
Example:
Given: 7
Output: 4  i.e f(4) = 7

Also, since a number *may* occur more than once in the given sequence, return the *last time* that number occurs.
Example:
Given: 22
here, f(10) = 22  and f(17) = 22
so, Output: 17

From the python code - I have observed that a number occurs utmost twice (not 100% sure though..).

My code to find the nth number in the series:

```
memo = {}
def rep(k):
    if k<=1:
        return 1
    if k == 2:
        return 2
    if not k in memo:
        if k%2==0:
            memo[k] = (k/2) + rep((k/2)+1) + rep(k/2)
        else:
            memo[k] = 1 + rep(((k-1)/2)-1) + rep((k-1)/2)
    value_key[memo[k]] = k
    return memo[k]
```

I have used `memo` to hash the values that I have already generated, but using this approach to generate and trying out number from 0 till I get a value that is equal to the given number (simple brute force)  takes forever and causes MemoryErrors for larger digits(Input will vary from 1 to 20 digits).

So, is there any relation between the given equations that I am missing?
If I could find a relation between `f(n)` (given input) and `n` - I think it can be easily implemented in code, but I am not able to simplify it mathematically - I've tried substituting one in another (the given recurrence relations) but so far I couldn't figure out anything.

Comment: What numbers appear twice?

Comment: I could not get a specific pattern but when they occur, the `n` that generate them are _relatively_ close to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit:

Now using binary search on closest values along with memoization, Needs testing, but the idea is straightforward. This still relies on the fact that `even` and `odd` are increasing sequences.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# inspired by your code
memo = {'even': {0: 1, 2: 2}, 'odd': {1: 1}}


def f(k):
    if k in memo['even']:
        return memo['even'][k]
    if k in memo['odd']:
        return memo['odd'][k]
    else:
        if k % 2 == 0:
            memo['even'][k] = (k / 2) + f((k / 2) + 1) + f(k / 2)
        else:
            memo['odd'][k] = 1 + f(((k - 1) / 2) - 1) + f((k - 1) / 2)
    return f(k)

# binary search on even values
def seek_even(x):
    left = 0
    right = f(x)
    if right % 2 != 0:
        right += 1
    middle = (right - left) / 2
    if middle % 2 != 0:
        middle += 1
    while f(middle) != x and left < middle < right:
        if f(middle) < x:
            left = middle
        else:
            right = middle
        middle = (left + right) / 2
        if middle % 2 != 0:
            middle += 1
    return middle

# binary search on odd values
def seek_odd(x):
    left = 1
    right = x
    if right % 2 == 0:
        right += 1
    middle = (right - left) / 2
    if middle % 2 == 0:
        middle += 1
    while f(middle) != x and left < middle < right:

        if f(middle) < x:
            left = middle
        else:
            right = middle
        middle = (left + right) / 2
        if middle % 2 == 0:
            middle += 1
    return middle


def seek(x):
    indices = [seek_even(x), seek_odd(x)]
    print "closest indices: " % indices
    return max(filter(lambda c: f(c) == x, indices) + [-1])

tests = [264227, 22, 10, 100000000000000000000, 31]
for i in tests:
    print "seek range [0, %d] for %d" % (f(i), i), seek(i)
```

Comment: You have started with 3 and you are doubling it every time you are searching for 'n' right? - but that does not guarantee the solution right?  Example: `f(12345) = 47703` now without actually calling `f` with that exact value, `memo` does not contain any information about 12345 or 47703 so just calling `get_x_for_f(47703)` after `f(10000000000000)` gives me an empty list, also since you are doubling the values, you are only generating a series of n = 3,6,12,24,48...

Comment: @user3581882 can you test now? You probably have some tests set up to see what's working, try the edited code please. Thanks :)

Comment: I have tried your edited code, and again the problem is the same - try it yourself, just generate a random `f(n)` say `f(53958)` which is `264227` now in a new program, after generating `f(100000000000)` when you try to run `seek(264227)` the result is -1 (it should be `264227`) and also, the memo has values from 1 to 28 (unequal intervals) and jumps to a 16 digit number all in between numbers are missed out - My opinion is that it is too hard to solve using plain programming tricks and that there may be some tricky math in it.

Comment: Could very well be. I'm useless at math. I'll try again when I get home

Comment: @user3581882 , can you test now? I think the problem was the by-value binary search (I'm at codemonkey's house!)